# Ubuntu on a Mac

Tags: ubuntu, mac, macbook-pro

Does anyone here have experience installing Ubuntu on their MacBook Pro? I wonder if features like multitouch would work on Ubuntu (or if there was anyway to make that work).

Has anyone here tried it? I'd like some advice on whether to do it or not/how to go about it etc.

Comment: It's been almost a month since the question was asked, if one of the answers fits please accept it, otherwise please explain why the answer does not fit. Thanks.

Comment: More complex [multi-touch features](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20013760-264.html) are coming in 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [Ubuntu 9.10 on my Macbook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) (not a Pro, it's the 2009 13" model) last year and it worked fairly well.  I had issues with kernel updates breaking my Broadcom (wireless) drivers, which resulted on me moving to [Sabayon Linux](http://www.sabayon.org/); it's been working beautifully on my Macbook ever since.

BTW, one of my friends runs Ubuntu 10.04 on his Pro and has never had an issue.

In answer to your question about features like multi-touch, it depends on the drivers and what the community pushes out.  Two-fingered scroll/click works just fine in Sabayon and Ubuntu, but I don't know if there are any drivers which take advantage of the other swipe/gestures of the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead, just follow the [Ubuntu download instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download). You might also want to sign up to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) and head over to the [Apple Users](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=328) section - plenty of Ubuntu experts there.

Try a live CD first - you'll be able to run Ubuntu to see if it works without doing anything permanent, although the live CD is slower than a real install.